# How can I use jquery each function on multiple inputs ?

Tags: jquery

I have this multiple textboxes in my html

```
<input type="text" name="publishername[]" class="form-control publishername">
<input type="text" name="publisherlocation[]" class="form-control publisherlocation" >
<input type="text" name="publisheremail[]" class="form-control publisheremail">
```

But how can i use each function on this textboxes?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking or what you want to achieve. However, it sounds like `$('input').each(...` may be what you need.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not explained what exactly you want to achieve using many functions at once, but I will try to help you.

```
<input type="text" name="publishername[]" class="form-control publishername">
<input type="text" name="publisherlocation[]" class="form-control publisherlocation" >
<input type="text" name="publisheremail[]" class="form-control publisheremail">
```

**Method 1.**

One is to combine your selectors for the event so that you would have

```
$("input[name='publishername'], input[name='publisherlocation'], input[name='publisheremail']").on('click', function() {
$('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);
});
```

**Method 2.**

The other is to define the bound code as an actual function, and call the function from each event binding

```
$("input[name='publishername']").on('click', doStuff);

$("input[name='publisherlocation']").on('click', doStuff);

$("input[name='publisheremail']").on('click', doStuff);

function doStuff() {
    $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);
}
```

**Method 3.**

Or you can combine both methods to have the following

```
$("input[name='publishername'], input[name='publisherlocation'], input[name='publisheremail']").on('click', doStuff);

function doStuff() {
    $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);
}
```

**Method 4.**

Using .each()

```
var publishername = '';             
  $('input[@name=publishername]').each(function(){
  publishername = publishername + '&publishername[]='+$(this).val();
});

var publisherlocation = ''; 
 $('input[@name=publisherlocation]').each(function(){
  publisherlocation = publisherlocation + '&publisherlocation[]='+ $(this).val();
});

var publisheremail = ''; 
 $('input[@name=publisheremail]').each(function(){
  publisheremail = publisheremail + '&publisheremail[]='+ $(this).val();
});
```

[Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: can you achieve it using .each? im trying to combine all those inputs

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want after this but this is how you can use `.each` on this.

```js
function getAll(){
$("input[type='text']").each(function () {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="publishername[]" class="form-control publishername">
<input type="text" name="publisherlocation[]" class="form-control publisherlocation" >
<input type="text" name="publisheremail[]" class="form-control publisheremail">
<button onclick="getAll()"> Get Values </button>
```

In this example, I am logging values of all `inputs` on console.

You can have an idea of how to do what you want

Comment: But how can i declare the $_POST on my php file after this ?